# Order of PHP function parameters

Tags: php

Can anyone explain the "standard" that is used for the order of PHP function parms please?

eg. is there some logic or reason why the STRTOK and EXPLODE functions, which both do vaguely similar things, have their parms in the opposite order to each other, or is it purely to make the syntax impossible for the casual user to remember??

Ditto for many other functions:

```
$x = strtok($string,' ');
$y = explode(' ',$string);
```

Comment: Many of PHP's functions (especially `str*()`) are simple wrappers of those in C libraries, and lots of those are inconsistent.  PHP's not known for consistency. Embrace it, love it, read the docs. :)

Comment: Even better, `implode()` can accepts its 2 args in _either order_ http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: There is no rhyme or reason lol. It's an open-source language and whoever makes a function useful enough to include it in the latest PHP build is the one that decides the fate of what you are inquiring about.

Comment: @user2191572 Actually loads of debate and voting happens behind modern additions to PHP. In the early days, functions got added as needed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you are correct but could you imagine what it would take to go back and modernize the functions that have been around since PHP 4.x?

Comment: I know it's just an example you chose here, but I would probably advise against `strtok()` anyway. Its use is confusing and old-fashioned and `explode()` is a more useful alternative almost all the time.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I will just go ahead and agree with your statement of ` Embrace it, love it, read the docs :)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MichaelBerkowski said, lots of the functions in PHP are built on top of the C libraries.  So, it's not entirely it's fault.

As far as "embrace it, love it", that's pretty hard, and so PHP is not my favorite language.

But, about the documentation, I found a downloadable help file to remind myself to be really useful because I can't remember the exact syntax: [download PHP docs as a help file](http://php.net/download-docs.php).

Note that some of the newer, more object-oriented parts of PHP are getting better on that regard.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I absolutely love the language. I just get sick of pulling up old code or googling it, every time I want to use any function. The ole brain ain't what it used to be! :-(

Comment: @user2605793 : Agreed!  Did you look at the download link?  It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Notepad++ as your editor you can check out enabling the auto-complete and function parameters hint available in the preferences:

[image]

I am sure there are many more editors and IDEs that support this but Notepad++ has been my favorite free editor.

Thanks to computers the ole brain doesn't have to be what it used to be =)